# how do i update database table by adding or substracting to/from initial data

Tags: laravel

I want to update my inventory when a new stock is created

i have tried these two non is working

```
  foreach( $stock->stock_items as $item)
    {
        DB::table('inventories')->where('product_id',$item['product_id'])
            ->update(
                  'available_quantity' => 'available_quantity' + $item['quanity'],
                  'available_amount'   => 'available_amount' + $item['unit_price']
            );
    }
```

With this when i use one 'increment' it works but when i chain the increments i get an error

```
  foreach( $stock->stock_items as $item)
    {
        DB::table('inventories')->where('product_id',$item['product_id'])
            ->increment('available_quantity',$item['quantity'])
            ->increment('available_amount',$item['unit_price']); 
    }
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: can you post the what error printed Sir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this it will fixed your issue:

```
DB::table('inventories')->where('product_id',$item['product_id'])->update([
    'available_quantity' => DB::raw('available_quantity + ' . $item["quantity"]),
    'available_amount' => DB::raw('available_amount + ' . $item["unit_price"]),
]);
```